# Partion based on Specified value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Am trying to write q query which Partition  based on  value 90. Below is My table

```
create table  #temp(StudentID char(2),    Status int) 
insert #temp  values('S1',75 ) 
insert #temp  values('S1',85 )
insert #temp  values('S1',90)
insert #temp  values('S1',85)
insert #temp  values('S1',83)
insert #temp  values('S1',90 ) 
insert #temp  values('S1',85)
insert #temp  values('S1',90)
insert #temp  values('S1',93 ) 
insert #temp  values('S1',93 ) 
insert #temp  values('S1',93 )
```

Required Out put:

```
ID  Status  Result
S1  75      0
S1  85      0
S1  90      0
S1  85      1
S1  83      1
S1  90      1
S1  85      2
S1  90      2
S1  93      3
S1  93      3   
S1  93      3
```

Please any one has the solution to partition based status id 90,Result should be 1,2,3 ..etc incrementing based on number of time value 90

Comment: Have you tried anything so far to solve the problem?

Comment: am trying to do with window function..but no luck..

Comment: And the question is ... ? `How to do it` isn't a question. You didn't even mention *what* you want to do. What do you mean "partition"? How is `Result` calculated? Are you trying to find ranges of incrementing values?

Comment: You can't do it with given sample data. You need a column that can be used for ordering

Comment: Can you share with us the attempt you have made against your actual data set? In the sample data provided there is no field that could be used in order to determine row order.

Comment: actually i dont require order..any order is ok..

Comment: @Ljt no it's not OK. Rows have no order unless you *specify* one. Just because you inserted the values like that doesn't mean they will be retrieved in that order. The server may well return all of them in reverse Status order if that's faster. What `Result` value would you expect then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that the actual question is "How can I find ranges/islands of incrementing values", the answer could use [LAG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to compare the current `Status` value with the previous one base on some order. If the previous value is 90, you have a new island :

```
declare @temp table (ID int identity PRIMARY KEY, StudentID char(2),    Status int) 

insert into @temp (StudentID,Status)
values
('S1',75), 
('S1',85),
('S1',90),
('S1',85),
('S1',83),
('S1',90), 
('S1',85),
('S1',90),
('S1',93), 
('S1',93), 
('S1',93);

select 
    * ,
    case LAG(Status,1,0) OVER (PARTITION BY StudentID ORDER BY ID) 
        when 90 then 1 else 0 end as NewIsland
from @temp
```

This returns :

```
+----+-----------+--------+-----------+
| ID | StudentID | Status | NewIsland |
+----+-----------+--------+-----------+
|  1 | S1        |     75 |         0 |
|  2 | S1        |     85 |         0 |
|  3 | S1        |     90 |         0 |
|  4 | S1        |     85 |         1 |
|  5 | S1        |     83 |         0 |
|  6 | S1        |     90 |         0 |
|  7 | S1        |     85 |         1 |
|  8 | S1        |     90 |         0 |
|  9 | S1        |     93 |         1 |
| 10 | S1        |     93 |         0 |
| 11 | S1        |     93 |         0 |
+----+-----------+--------+-----------+
```

You can create an Island ID from this by summing all NewIsland values *before* the current one, using SUM with the ROWS clause of [OVER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
with islands as 
(
    select 
        * ,
        case LAG(Status,1,0) OVER (PARTITION BY StudentID ORDER BY ID) 
            when 90 then 1 else 0 end as NewIsland
    from @temp
)
select * , 
       SUM(NewIsland) OVER (PARTITION BY StudentID ORDER BY ID ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) 
from islands
```

This produces :

```
+----+-----------+--------+-----------+--------+
| ID | StudentID | Status | NewIsland | Result |
+----+-----------+--------+-----------+--------+
|  1 | S1        |     75 |         0 |      0 |
|  2 | S1        |     85 |         0 |      0 |
|  3 | S1        |     90 |         0 |      0 |
|  4 | S1        |     85 |         1 |      1 |
|  5 | S1        |     83 |         0 |      1 |
|  6 | S1        |     90 |         0 |      1 |
|  7 | S1        |     85 |         1 |      2 |
|  8 | S1        |     90 |         0 |      2 |
|  9 | S1        |     93 |         1 |      3 |
| 10 | S1        |     93 |         0 |      3 |
| 11 | S1        |     93 |         0 |      3 |
+----+-----------+--------+-----------+--------+
```

BTW this is a case of the wider Gaps & Islands problem in SQL.

**UPDATE**

LAG and OVER are available in all supported SQL Server versions, ie SQL Server 2012 and later. OVER is also available in SQL Server 2008 but not LAG. In those versions different, slower techniques were used to calculate islands: [The SQL of Gaps and Islands in Sequences](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/the-sql-of-gaps-and-islands-in-sequences/)

In most cases ROW_NUMBER() is used to calculate the row ordering, which results in one extra CTE. This can be avoided if the desired ordering is the same as the ID, or any other unique incrementing column. The following query returns the same results as the query that uses `LAG` :

```
select 
    * ,
    case when exists (select ID 
                      from @temp t1 
                      where t1.StudentID=t2.StudentID 
                            and t1.ID=t2.ID-1 
                            and t2.status=90) then 1
         else 0 end
        as NewIsland
from @temp t2
```

This query returns 1 if there's any row with the same StudentID, Status 90 and ID or ROW_NUMBER one less, ie the same as LAG(,1).

After that we just need to SUM previous values. While SUM OVER was available in 2008, it only supported PARTITION BY. We need to use another subquery :

```
;with islands as 
(
    select 
        * ,
    case when exists (select ID from @temp t1 where t1.StudentID=t2.StudentID and t1.ID=t2.ID-1 and t2.status=90) then 1
         else 0 end
        as NewIsland
    from @temp t2
)
select * , 
       (select ISNULL(SUM(NewIsland),0) 
        from islands i1 
        where i1.ID<i2.ID) AS Result
from islands i2
```

This sums all `NewIsland` values for rows with an ID less than the current one.

**Performance**

All those subqueries result in a lot of repeated scans. Suprisingly though, the older query is *faster* than the query with LAG because the first query has to order temporary results multiple times and filter by Status, with a 45% vs 55% execution plan cost.

Things change dramatically when an index is added :

```
declare @temp table ( ID int identity PRIMARY KEY, StudentID char(2),    Status int, 
                      INDEX IX_TMP(StudentID,ID,Status))
```

The multiple sorts disappear and the costs become 80% vs 20%. The query just scans the index values once without sorting the intermediate results.

The subquery version wasn't able to take advantage of the index

**UPDATE 2**

`uzi` suggested that removing LAG and summing only up to the previous row would be better :

```
select * , 
       SUM(case when status =90 then 1 else 0 end) 
           OVER (PARTITION BY StudentID 
                 ORDER BY ID ROWS 
                 BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) 
from @temp;
```

Semantically, this is the same thing - for each row find all previous ones, calculate 1 for the 90s and 0 for the other rows, and sum them.

The server generate similar execution plans in both cases. The LAG version used two streaming aggregate operators while the version without it one. The end result for **this** limited data set was essentially the same though.

For a larger data set the results may be different, eg if the server has to spool data to `tempdb` because they didn't fit in memory.

Comment: LAG is available on SQL Server 2012+, he is using 2008.

Comment: @Ezlo doesn't say so in the question. 2012 is the earliest supported version anyway. This is *still* a gaps & islands question. Even in older versions you still have to find the islands first and then calculate the rank

Comment: Thanks a lot @PanagiotisKanavos with clear explanation.

Comment: Query can be improved by removing `LAG` function and changing `sum` function to `...rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding`

Comment: @Ezlo updated with a 2008 solution and performance comparison

Comment: @uzi not really - the execution plans are identical but the query becomes harder to understand

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos indeed, only one sorting, I thought there would be two with `LAG`

Comment: @uzi that's why indexing has such a huge effect

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is not a very good solution, but it works.

```
SELECT StudentID ID 
, Marks Status
, CASE
WHEN Marks = 90 
THEN SUM(q) OVER(order by row) - 1 
ELSE SUM(q) OVER(order by row)
END Result 
FROM (  
    SELECT row_number() OVER(order by StudentID desc) row
        , *
        , CASE 
        WHEN Marks = 90 
        THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 
        END q
    FROM #temp
) a
```

Comment: Thanks @ F.Valeriy

Comment: This *won't* work without some other column to order by, like an incrementing ID. All rows have the same `StudentID` value so the `ROW_NUMBER()` results will be arbitrary

Comment: As I understood from the question, by condition, it is necessary to use temporary tables without using additional fields. Because the data in the temporary tables are stored physically in the database (unlike the virtual tables), the query will return the records in the same order as they were added. I agree that for real problems this query is not applicable, but for the solution of this example it is suitable.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use *subquery*

```
select *,
        coalesce((select sum(case when Marks = 90 then 1 else 0 end) 
                  from table 
                  where studentid = t.studentid and 
                        ? < t.?) , 0) as Result
from table t;
```

However, `?` (i.e. `id`) specify your actual data ordering columns